# Can not connect to the target collection using azure-devops-migration-tools. Getting "You are not authorized to access xxxxx"

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

Using azure-devops-migration-tools I can not get it to connect to the target collection.

I am migrating from the local tfs server to the cloud Azure DevOps.

The issue what I am observing :

```
[18:24:07 INF] TfsMigrationClient::GetDependantTfsCollection:AuthenticationMode(AccessToken)
[18:24:07 INF] TfsMigrationClient::GetDependantTfsCollection: Connecting with AccessToken
[18:24:07 INF] MigrationClient: Connecting to https://dev.azure.com/brands/
[18:24:07 ERR] Unable to configure store
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/brands/. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

My manager used this a while back and thinks he remembers that a popup appears when you run it asking for you credentials - I never get any kind of popup. I have rebooted and cleared caches.

It appears that it is looking for an access token. I did generate one in the destination Azure DevOps account - where/how do I use it in this case?

Is there a different way to set it up so it has access to the destination or asks me for a password?

I launch the tool in Powershell with

```
 .\migration.exe execute -c configuration.json
```

The contents of my configuration.json -

```
{
    "Version": "11.9",
    "LogLevel": "Verbose",
    "TelemetryEnableTrace": false,
    "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
    "Source": {
        "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
        "Collection": "http://tgi-dev-004.10.local:8080/tfs/Ten_Projects/",
        "Project": "TenSuite",
        "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
        "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false
    },
    "Target": {
        "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
        "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/brands/",
        "Project": "10e",
        "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
        "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false
    },
    "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
        "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
    },
    "GitRepoMapping": null,
    "Processors": [
    {
        "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
        "ReplayRevisions": true,
        "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
        "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
        "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
        "UpdateSourceReflectedId": false,
        "BuildFieldTable": false,
        "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
        "OrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
        "Enabled": true,
        "LinkMigration": true,
        "AttachmentMigration": true,
        "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
        "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": true,
        "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
        "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
        "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
        "AttachmentMazSize": 480000000
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an old version of the config. Please use `migration.exe init` to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Under `Source` and `Target` there is a property where you should add the token.

Please read the documentation with the examples.

https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/